# Change Link BG Color onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the BG color of a link when the user clicks on it/onClick. Here is the code I am currently working on;

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Link Drop Down</a>
```

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById("dropbtn").onclick = function()
    {
        this.style.background = '#FFF';
    }
}
```

But it didn't worked and I am not sure why.

Comment: onclick is an event handler: a function that receives event information when the corresponding object has the event triggered. You miss the param `(ev)`, and `ev.target.style.background='#FFF'`.

Comment: Tried, but did not worked

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Link Drop Down</a>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("dropbtn").onclick = function(event) {
    var drop_down = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (!drop_down.classList.contains('show')) {
        drop_down.classList.add('show');
        this.style.background = '#FFF';
    }
    else {
        drop_down.classList.remove('show');
        this.style.background = '';
    }
    return true; 
  }
}
myFunction();
```

Basically you have to install the `onclick` Event handler (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) , which receives an `event` parameter with event info. `this` inside it actually points to the element with id=`dropbtn`, so you can either reference it directly as in your question or get the reference that is on `event.target`.

#### EDIT

Actually I was wrong, sorry, `this` indeed points to the element clicked. Fixed the answer.

Comment: It partially worked. But two issues arises.
1. The drop down link needs to click twice to open the drop down.
2. The background color remain there even if the drop down has been closed.

Comment: 1. `toggle` removes the class if it's already present in the element, so check if class `show` isn't initially applied. 2. Yes... the line that applies the background `#FFF` must be changed but I think you can handle it :)

Comment: Though it didn't worked what I expected, yet thank you for your good time. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction(e)" class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">Link Drop Down</a>


function myFunction(e) {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  e.target.style.background = '#FFF';
}
```